# What is an easy way to install a unix terminal with a C++ mingw compiler?

Tags: c++, windows, makefile, mingw

I'm going to teach students to use SFML with C++, and I'm afraid the school doesn't have visual studio C++ installed, or will be a bit heavy to use for those students.

I want to have a plan B and have the option of a simple makefile that I can build on windows with SFML.

https://www.sfml-dev.org/download/sfml/2.5.1/ this page offers binaries compiled with different, specific versions of mingw with their respective mingw package links, unfortunately mingw doesn't include an unix terminal, like the one included with git-bash, so I can run a makefile.

What are the steps required to have a problem unix terminal, running in windows, minsys, msys2 or not, that can work well with those mingw packages? I have trouble finding help or proper instructions.

Comment: Are you looking for a terminal or a shell, or both?

Comment: Why don't you simply install `git-bash` and `mingw`?

Comment: msys and the likes are pretty much obsolete these days - Windows Subsystem for Linux comes with a full Linux terminal as well as full Linux everything.

Comment: @RenaudPacalet I do have git-bash installed, how can I point it to mingw and mingw-bash?

Comment: Well, I am not an expert of these environments that try to mimic GNU/Linux under Windows, but as you already have a bash with git-bash, you don't need another. And the mingw environment is located somewhere on your `C:` drive. Try `ls c:/mingw*`, maybe.

Answer (score 1):

You want https://www.msys2.org/

It provides bash terminal and already contains mingw compiler. Perhaps it even has SFML packages already.